# How to use qunit-bdd with ember-qunit?

Tags: ember.js, qunit-bdd, ember-qunit

Originally posted on the mailing list by Andreas Haller, reposting here so that the "qunit-bdd" tag will be available for others to use.

> [ember-qunit](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit) adds a handy `moduleFor` helper which one can use as an alternative to QUnit's `module` function. Now ember-qunit abstracts things so that i never have to use the module function and i don't know if i could. My question is twofold:
>
> 1. Does `describe` defacto act the same as `module`?
> 2. How can i use ember-qunit's `moduleFor` / `moduleForComponent`?
>
> If there is no solution for #2 yet something like `describe(moduleFor('controller:posts'), function() { … })` would be nice.

Comment: Note that Qunit now supports nested modules out of the box. Support for this in ember-qunit is being tracked here: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/issues/208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`describe` in qunit-bdd does mostly act the same as `module` in QUnit. The difference is that they can be nested in qunit-bdd and each level of nesting will correspond to a `module` call with the names joined together. For example, this will result in three calls to `module`:

```
describe('Foo', function() {
  it('is a function', function() {
    expect(typeof Foo).to.equal('function');
  });

  describe('#foo', function() {
    it('says FOO', function() {
      expect(new Foo().foo()).to.equal('FOO');
    });
  });

  describe('#bar', function() {
    it('says BAR', function() {
      expect(new Foo().bar()).to.equal('BAR');
    });
  });
});
```

Because there is no way to control what `module` function is called, there's no way (yet) to use qunit-bdd with ember-qunit. We are discussing how to change that. Your suggestion could work, but would require modification to qunit-bdd explicitly for ember-qunit. I'd prefer to have the shared code in ember-qunit and then have a thin wrapper for qunit-bdd. Perhaps something similar to yours, but keeping the API to qunit-bdd the same:

```
describe('PostsController', testFor('controller:posts', function() {
  it('has a length', function() {
    expect(this.subject.length).to.be.defined();
  });
}));
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.